# DrawerLayout inflate error, with some customer style

Tags: android, android-layout

I am try to use DrawerLayout. I learn from the method from this project http://git.oschina.net/oschina/android-app
I gusses the problem is in attribute or style, but I cannot find it.
now I will show me code.

in activity_main.xml:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />


<fragment
    android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    android:name="com.xjtu.wangshuai.vstarcoffee.NavigationDrawerFragment"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />
```

and in fragment_navigation_drawer.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="?attr/layout_bg_normal">

<com.xjtu.wangshuai.vstarcoffee.widget.CustomerScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <include layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer_items"/>
</com.xjtu.wangshuai.vstarcoffee.widget.CustomerScrollView>
```

CustomerScrollView is a customer widget, it can let the list(some LinearLayout) can be Scroll.

```
public class CustomerScrollView extends ScrollView {

private static final int size = 4;//表示拖动的距离为屏幕的高度的1/4
private View inner;
private float y;
private Rect normal = new Rect();

public CustomerScrollView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CustomerScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
protected void onFinishInflate() {
    super.onFinishInflate();
    if (getChildCount() > 0) {
        inner = getChildAt(0);
    }
}

@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if (inner == null) {
        return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
    } else {
        commOnTouchEvent(ev);
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
}

public void commOnTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    int action = ev.getAction();
    switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            y = ev.getY();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            if (isNeedAnimation()) {
                // Log.v("mlguitar", "will up and animation");
                animation();
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            final float preY = y;
            float nowY = ev.getY();
            /**
             * size=4 表示 拖动的距离为屏幕的高度的1/4
             */
            int deltaY = (int) (preY - nowY) / size;
            // 滚动
            // scrollBy(0, deltaY);

            y = nowY;
            if (isNeedMove()) {
                if (normal.isEmpty()) {
                    normal.set(inner.getLeft(), inner.getTop(),
                            inner.getRight(), inner.getBottom());
                    return;
                }
                int yy = inner.getTop() - deltaY;

                // 移动布局
                inner.layout(inner.getLeft(), yy, inner.getRight(),
                        inner.getBottom() - deltaY);
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

public void animation() {
    TranslateAnimation ta = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, inner.getTop(),
            normal.top);
    ta.setDuration(200);
    inner.startAnimation(ta);
    inner.layout(normal.left, normal.top, normal.right, normal.bottom);
    normal.setEmpty();
}

public boolean isNeedAnimation() {
    return !normal.isEmpty();
}

public boolean isNeedMove() {
    int offset = inner.getMeasuredHeight() - getHeight();
    int scrollY = getScrollY();
    if (scrollY == 0 || scrollY == offset) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
    }
}
```

in fragment_navigation_drawer_items.xml:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#e2e2e2"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/menu_item_order_record"
    style="@style/MenuItemLayoutStyle" >

    <ImageView
        style="@style/MenuItemImageViewStyle"
        android:background="@drawable/drawer_menu_icon_blog_nor"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />

    <TextView
        style="@style/MenuItemTextViewStyle"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/drawer_order_record" />
</LinearLayout>

<View
    style="@style/h_line" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/menu_item_member_points"
    style="@style/MenuItemLayoutStyle" >

    <ImageView
        style="@style/MenuItemImageViewStyle"
        android:background="@drawable/drawer_menu_icon_blog_nor"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />

    <TextView
        style="@style/MenuItemTextViewStyle"
        android:text="@string/drawer_member_points" />
</LinearLayout>

<View
    style="@style/h_line" />
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/menu_item_member_card"
    style="@style/MenuItemLayoutStyle" >
    <ImageView
        style="@style/MenuItemImageViewStyle"
        android:background="@drawable/drawer_menu_icon_blog_nor"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />

    <TextView
        style="@style/MenuItemTextViewStyle"
        android:text="@string/drawer_menmber_card" />
</LinearLayout>

<View
    style="@style/h_line" />
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/menu_item_message"
    style="@style/MenuItemLayoutStyle" >

    <ImageView
        style="@style/MenuItemImageViewStyle"
        android:background="@drawable/drawer_menu_icon_blog_nor"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />

    <TextView
        style="@style/MenuItemTextViewStyle"
        android:text="@string/drawer_message" />
</LinearLayout>

<View
    style="@style/h_line" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/menu_item_vstar_set"
    style="@style/MenuItemLayoutStyle" >

    <ImageView
        style="@style/MenuItemImageViewStyle"
        android:background="@drawable/drawer_menu_icon_blog_nor"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />

    <TextView
        style="@style/MenuItemTextViewStyle"
        android:text="@string/drawer_vstar_set" />
</LinearLayout>

<View
    style="@style/h_line" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/menu_item_settings"
    style="@style/MenuItemLayoutStyle" >

    <ImageView
        style="@style/MenuItemImageViewStyle"
        android:background="@drawable/drawer_menu_icon_blog_nor"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />

    <TextView
        style="@style/MenuItemTextViewStyle"
        android:text="@string/drawer_settings" />
</LinearLayout>

<View
    style="@style/h_line" />
```

But i got the error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.xjtu.wangshuai.vstarcoffee/com.xjtu.wangshuai.vstarcoffee.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2508)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2570)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:167)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5590)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:964)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:759)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:916)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:802)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
        at com.xjtu.wangshuai.vstarcoffee.NavigationDrawerFragment.onCreateView(NavigationDrawerFragment.java:94)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1786)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:920)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1206)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2159)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:297)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreateView(ActionBarActivity.java:547)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:228)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:102)
        at com.xjtu.wangshuai.vstarcoffee.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:60)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6021)


   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 13
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:747)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3823)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:518)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:215)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:211)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java
```

Comment: Can you post the code for `com.xjtu.wangshuai.vstarcoffee.widget.CustomerScrollView`

Answer (score 0):

In activity_main.xml change fragment attribute

android:name="com.xjtu.wangshuai.vstarcoffee.NavigationDrawerFragment"

to

class="com.xjtu.wangshuai.vstarcoffee.NavigationDrawerFragment"

Hope this helps...

Comment: I try to use your suggestion, but the problem is still exists.